# need of datastructure to store 3 datasets

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I am having 3 datasets, say A B and C.
A contains single array of 5 elements. B contains a 2D array and C also contains a 2D array.
A contains 5 elements which are independent of B and C.
for each element in A, an array is associated in B and for each element in that array of B, an array is associated in C..  so i want to store these data sets in a data structure so that selecting an element in A should give appropriate element array in B and selecting an element in that array of B should give an elements of C.. can anybody suggest me one..i am using java programming language to implement this data structure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for a mapping from elements of A to elements of B, and from those to C. The easiest way to achieve this would be to use some `HashMaps`, or any other class implementing the `Map` interface, for example:

```
List<TypeA> a = new ArrayList<TypeA>();
Map<TypeA, List<TypeB>> b = new HashMap<TypeA, List<TypeB>>();
Map<TypeB, List<TypeC>> c = new HashMap<TypeB, List<TypeC>>();
```

This way, `a` is just your array *A*. `b` maps the elements from `a` to lists, which are the rows in your 2D array *B*. Similarly, `c` maps the elements from those rows to lists, which are the rows in *C*.

Alternatively, you could use a single nested `Map` for all three:

```
Map<TypeA, Map<TypeB, List<TypeC>>> abc = 
        new HashMap<TypeA, Map<TypeB, List<TypeC>>>;
```

This way, the keys in `abc` correspond to your array *A*. The value to each key is again a map, whose keys are the elements of the row in *B* corresponding to that element from *A*. Finally, the values for each of those keys are the rows in *C* corresponding to those elements in *B*.

Note that the keys in a `Map` are not ordered, so if order is important (for example if you have to iterate over *A* in any specific order, or if you have to access them by some index) you should go with the first solution. If order is important for `b` and `c` as well, you could try this:

```
List<TypeA> a = new ArrayList<TypeA>();
List<List<TypeB>> b = new ArrayList<List<TypeB>>();
List<List<TypeC>> c = new ArrayList<List<TypeC>>();
Map<TypeA, Integer> ab = new HashMap<TypeA, Integer>();
Map<TypeB, Integer> bc = new HashMap<TypeB, Integer>();
```

Here, `a`, `b` and `c` correspond directly to your *A*, *B* and *C* (if you know how many elements they will have you can use arrays, too). `ab` and `bc` then hold the mapping from each element of `a` (or `b`) to the corresponding indices in `b` (or `c`). Note that you will have to update `ab` and `bc` whenever you insert elements into `a` or `b`.

Thus, if order is not important, I would recommend the *second* solution, since this way you do not have to 'synchronize' `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//         <Value, index in A>
vector<pair<Value, int>> A;
//                <Value, index in C>  
vector<vector<pair<Value, int>> B;
//            Values in C
vector<vector<Value>> C;
```

If my understanding of your question is correct, in C++ one would do the above, not sure about Java.

Comment: can u please explain the syntax and of "vector" u have used.. i may be able to figure out one in java.